# How to get property from context property placeholder tag inside custom java component

Tags: spring, mule

I have Mule Configuration that defines

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/mule-sw.properties"/>
```

And I also have a custom component class in Java which use @Lookup annotation on one of my field

```
@Lookup("file-path")
private String path;
```

Considering my "mule-sw.properties" is like this

```
file-path=C:/hello.txt
```

After I start up the Mule App, I always get Deploy Exception

```
org.mule.api.expression.RequiredValueException: "Required object not found in registry of Type "class java.lang.String" with name "file-path" on object "class component.CustomComponent"
```

I also tried to change the @Lookup("file-path") with @Lookup("${file-path}") with no success.

Anyone can give me a better solution ?
Any help is kindly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The @Lookup annotation is designed to retrieve [objects from the registry](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Lookup+Annotation) , whereas what you are trying to do is to assign a value to an attribute of your custom component.

There are 2 way to do that:

1) Through property injection, i.e. you declare your component like the following:

```
<custom-component class="org.myCompany.CustomComponent">
    <property name="file-path" value="${file-path}" />
</custom-component>
```

2) Through Spring EL support and the @Value annotation, i.e. you annotate your attribute in the following way

```
@Value("${file-path}")
private String path;
```

I'd recommend the first approach since it is easier to maintain from a flow perspective

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. 1st approach works for me by adding setter method to the custom component. As for 2nd approach, it doesn't work, I think the @Value annotation doesn't get processed if I use Mule to instantiate the custom component.

Answer (score 3):

```
@Value("#{'${file-path}'}")
private String path;
```

Give this a shot. I think you need to wrap it in an EL block #{} for it to be properly recognized.

Comment: Hi Chronowraith .... even if i try this EL block thing , I am not able to access th property ... how do i achieve getting properties into my java class via propertiesplaceholder